# React js constant object value isn't working with `useState()` as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with input fields which is getting added dynamically. There is initial value for the input fields, which i have set in constant and using accordingly.

The issue i am facing is, whatever I added new items and type whatever i**t update the same value for all the inputs** as well. I am sharing my script that i am trying.

> constant file
> `src/constant/index.js`

```js
.
.
export const NEW_TAX_LINE = {taxTitle:'',taxType:'percentage',taxRate:10};
.
.
```

> component file `src/components/taxOptions.js

```js
import { NEW_TAX_LINE } from "../../../../constants";
import { useState, useEffect, lazy } from "react";

const TaxItems = lazy(()=> import('./TaxItems'));

function TaxOptions() {

    const [taxLineItems, setTaxLineItems] = useState([NEW_TAX_LINE]);

    const handleChangeTaxItems = (event, index, PROPKEY) => {
        console.log({event, index, PROPKEY});
        
        const _taxDetails = [...taxLineItems];
        _taxDetails[index][PROPKEY] = event.target.value;
        setTaxLineItems(_taxDetails);
    }

    function handleAddNewTax(){
        setTaxLineItems( [...taxLineItems, NEW_TAX_LINE] )
    }

    return <>
        .
        .
        {taxLineItems.map((item, index) => (
            <TaxItems
                key={`tax-item-${index}`} 
                item={item}
                index={index}
                onChange={handleChangeTaxItems} 
            />
        ))}
        .
        .
        <Button 
            variant="contained"
            size="small"
            startIcon={<AddCircleOutlineIcon sx={{fontSize:'16px !important'}} />}
            className="add-tax-button"
            onClick={()=>handleAddNewTax()}
            >
            Add new
        </Button>
    </>
}

export default TaxOptions;
```

> `TaxItems.js`

```js
function TaxItems(props){

    return <>
    <TableRow >
            <TableCell className="tax-items" component="td" scope="row">
                <InputBase
                    className="i-item-cls"
                    // sx={{ flex: 1, mt:0}}
                    placeholder="Tax type"
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'unit-price' }}
                    name="unitprice"                     
                    fullWidth
                    value={props.item.taxTitle}
                    onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event, props.index, "taxTitle")}
                />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell className="tax-items" align='right'>
                <Grid sx={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <InputBase
                        className="i-item-cls i-taxrate"
                        placeholder="Tax Rate"
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Tax rate' }}
                        name="unitprice"                     
                        fullWidth
                        value={props.item.taxRate}
                        onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event, props.index, "taxRate")}
                    />
                    <Typography sx={{fontSize:'16px',fontWeight:'bold'}} component="span">%</Typography>
                </Grid>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </>
}

export default TaxItems;
```

> here is the screenshot or refr.

[image: Here is screenshot for the refr.]

Don't know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function handleAddNewTax(){
  setTaxLineItems( [...taxLineItems, NEW_TAX_LINE] )
}
```

NEW_TAX_LINE is the link to object, not the object itself. So you add the same link everytime you add new tax. You should add new object like this:

```
function handleAddNewTax(){
  setTaxLineItems( [...taxLineItems, Object.assign({}, NEW_TAX_LINE)] )
}
```

Comment: it works. Thanks i also find another way changing in constant file like following `export function NEW_TAX_LINE(){ return {taxTitle:'',taxType:'percentage',taxRate:10}}` and in component `NEW_TAX_LINE()`